# Equivalent in EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

What is equivalent of this code in emgucv:

```
    cv::Mat marker = cv::Mat::zeros(im.size(), CV_8UC1);
```

This is in opencv now!

I couldn't find a wrapper for Mat!

Comment: You might consider renaming your question so that it can be found by other people looking for answers on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see at the top of the Documentation of the `Matrix` class [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html), you cannot initialize a matrix with explicit values. You can, however, initialize a matrix with a certain size and then set its values to zero by calling `myMatrix.SetZero()`